# Плагин в качестве модуля

Tags: wordpress

Доброго дня!

Подскажите, может кто делал плагин как модуль к сайту? Т.е., я хочу, что бы например при открытии mysite.com/myplugin/ выводилась в паблик доступе какая-нибудь внутренняя страница плагина. Может есть у кого примеры как это сделать?

Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете страницу `myplugin.php`, кладете ее, например, в корень папки с плагином. Следующий фрагмент кода позволяет проверить, происходит ли обращение к странице с таким именем, и если да, то применяет нужный шаблон.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_include_function', 1 );

function template_include_function( $template_path ) {
    if(is_page('myplugin')){
       $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/myplugin.php';
    }
    return $template_path;
}
```

Comment: Кажется, это то, что мне нужно!

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess правило переадресации , хоть в космос хоть на файл плагина

Comment: Окей, какой смысл тогда от плагина, если человеку нужно еще вручную будет добавлять в корень вордпресса в .htaccess огромное количество строк с реврайтами?

Comment: что мешает сделать общее правило для определенной папки ?